# List comprehension with multiple for loop

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I try to do list comprehension with reading from CL arguments

```
weights = [[int(arg) for arg in sys.argv[i]] for i in range(3,7)]
```

This is what I achieved, but the output is a multidimensional array like:

```
[[3], [4], [5], [6]]
```

What I try to get with one line of list comprehension is:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: remove `[  ]`...?

Comment: @Joonyoung No, you'd need to flip the loops

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating this. If you want command-line arguments 3-6 as ints, do this:

```
weights = [int(arg) for arg in sys.argv[3:7]]
```

Note that if there are missing args, this won't throw an `IndexError` like yours. If you need that behaviour, try this instead:

```
weights = [int(sys.argv[i]) for i in range(3, 7)]
```

And if you want even better CL arg parsing, check out [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html).

---

Keep in mind that the elements of `sys.argv` are **strings**, and if you iterate over a string as in `c for c in sys.argv[3]`, you get *characters**, which means if you gave a 2-digit weight on the command line like `14`, it would be split into its digits, `1` and `4`. If that's what you actually want, do this:

```
weights = [int(c) for i in range(3, 7) for c in sys.argv[i]]
```

<sup>* Technically strings of length 1</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use enumerate. Enumerate works like this:

```
a = ['a','b','c']
for i in enumerate(a):
     print(i)

#outputs
(0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(2, 'c')

#This is the solution
[int(arg) for index,arg in enumerate(sys.argv) if index in range(3,7)]
```